# How can I get the nested list of object with reactive couchbase?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, reactive-programming, couchbase

I recently started reviewing/learning some about reactive couchbase and I'm trying to implement a sample using that technology with spring data and spring boot, I have the following models:

```
@Document
public class Person {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Field
    private String name;
    @Field
    private String lastName;
    @Field
    private List<Address> address;
    // Getters & Setters
}

@Document
public class Address {
    @Id
    private String code;
    @Field
    private String mainStreet;
    @Field
    private String secondStreet;
    // Getters & Setters
}
```

**Repositories:**

```
@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "address")
public interface AddressRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Address, String> {
}

@N1qlPrimaryIndexed
@ViewIndexed(designDoc = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveCouchbaseRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

**Service:**

```
public interface PersonService {
    Flux<Person> getAllPersons();
    Mono<Person> getPerson(String id);
    Flux<Address> getAddressesByPerson(String id);
}

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Override
    public Flux<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Person> getPerson(String id) {
        return personRepository.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<Address> getAddressesByPerson(String id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample_couchbase")
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;

    @GetMapping("/people")
    public Flux<Person> getAllPersons() {
        return personService.getAllPersons();
    }

    @GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> getPersonsById(@PathVariable String id) {
        return personService.getPerson(id)
                            .map(person -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(person))
                            .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
}
```

As so far this works well, I can retrieve all the people and also filter by an id of a specific person, on the other hand I would like to retrieve all list of addresses of a specific person, I mean I have this document in couchbase:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Scooby",
  "lastName": "Doo",
  "address": [
    {
      "code": "A1",
      "mainStreet": "AAA",
      "secondStreet": "BBB",
      "phone": "11111",
      "place": "home"
    },
    {
      "code": "A2",
      "mainStreet": "CCC",
      "secondStreet": "DDD",
      "phone": "22222",
      "place": "work"
    },
    {
      "code": "A3",
      "mainStreet": "EEE",
      "secondStreet": "FFF",
      "phone": "33333",
      "place": "treasury"
    }
  ],
  "classType": "com.jcalvopinam.model.Person"
}
```

When I call the service e.g.: `http://localhost:8080/sample_couchbase/person/1/addresses` I want to get this:

```
"address": [
    {
      "code": "A1",
      "mainStreet": "AAA",
      "secondStreet": "BBB",
      "phone": "11111",
      "place": "home"
    },
    {
      "code": "A2",
      "mainStreet": "CCC",
      "secondStreet": "DDD",
      "phone": "22222",
      "place": "work"
    },
    {
      "code": "A3",
      "mainStreet": "EEE",
      "secondStreet": "FFF",
      "phone": "33333",
      "place": "treasury"
    }
  ]
```

I imagined create in the repository a method something like this:

```
Mono<Person> findById(String id);
```

And in the service layer I imagine getting the whole object and then filtering by Address, but this is something different from what I'm used to doing, now I'm using Mono and Flux and not a simple object or a List, so I don't know how to do that, can someone give me an idea? or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I found an easy way to retrieve the Addresses of a specific Person, I used a query where I specified what I want to retrieve:

```
@Query("SELECT addresses, META(sample).id as _ID, META(sample).cas as _CAS FROM `sample` WHERE id = $1")
Flux<Person> findAddressesByPerson(String id);
```

I noticed that it is necessary to specify the `META(sample).id as _ID` and `META(sample).cas as _CAS` attributes to avoid the following error:

`org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?; nested exception is rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.java.query.DefaultAsyncN1qlQueryRow.class`

If you want to take a look at the implementation in more detail, here is the sample: https://github.com/juanca87/sample-couchbase-rx